# RSS feeds with php and symfony more help needed please

Tags: php, rss, symfony-1.4

i read through the below:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276162/creating-a-rss-feed-in-symfony
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-phprss/
http://www.carronmedia.com/create-an-rss-feed-with-php/
```

i added in factories.yml:

```
all:
  request:
  param:
  formats:
    rss: application/rss+xml
```

i added in routing.yml:

```
rss_every_content:
   url:    /rss/all
   param: { module: content, action: index, sf_format: rss }
   requirements:
   sf_method: [get]
```

i added in /rainbow_code/phoenix/plugins/rainbowCodePlugin/modules/profile/templates

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://www.rainbowcode.net/index.php/profile/home" title="Subscribe to RSS" />
```

then the code in indexSuccess.xml.php that i found on [Creating a rss feed in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276162/creating-a-rss-feed-in-symfony), where do i put this? in which folder?

where do i go from here please?
i also installed the sfFeed2Plugin and sfWebBrowserPlugin but dont know how tho apply/use these

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexSuccess.xml.php` should be put in the `templates` folder of your content module.

Comment: thank you, i run ubuntu and when i click on the rss feed icon(want to see how it works) i just get xml?? or are rss feeds a windows thing?

Comment: Like most of the things you see in your web browser, rss is platform-independant, so it should work the same on both OSs. rss is an xml (html too by the way) but firefox should interpret it and present it to you in a special fashion. Here is an rss feed so that you can see what I mean : http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/symfony*

Comment: im afraid i just get raw xml in chrome and ff. there is a "question feed" icon here at the bottom right, when i click on it i get raw xml on a white page! is there a setting i must set? when i click on your link i get the same :(

Comment: Must be a browser setting... you're supposed to get something like this : http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/subscribing_firefox.jpg

Comment: i tested this on win 7 so know what i am supposed to get:) i will go through the settings.

Comment: FYI, I'm using firefox on the latest ubuntu, so it really must be a matter of settings.

Comment: aah it works perfect in FF. I subscribed to the feed choosing live bookmarks. how will i be notified of updates on this feed?? i have a "Classifieds" tab in the bookmark toolbar, when i click on it i get a dropdown of classifieds.. will this be updated continuously? thanks very much